# What is the DynamicException equivalent in the post-ghc-7.6.1 world?

Tags: haskell, ghc

`DynamicException` and `throwDyn` and `throwDynTo` used to be in the `Control.OldException` module. Now that `OldException` is gone for good, packages that relied on it are broken.

Is there an equivalent of `DynamicException` in the `ExtensibleException` package or elsewhere? I'd like to get away with minimal changes.

Context: I'm trying to build lambdabot with GHC 7.6.1. The broken file is `Signal.hs` in `lambdabot-utils`.

**Update** Is there some kind of guide for porting old exceptions code to new extensible exceptions? `lambdabot` uses `OldException` in several places, a quick fix doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Why not just `Control.Exception`? It supports arbitrarily typed exceptions as data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalents of these functions in the new `Control.Exception` are simply `throw`, `throwTo` and `catch`, as `Control.Exception` supports dynamic exceptions by default.

The main difference between the old interface and the new one is that these functions have an `Exception` constraint rather than `Typeable`. However, in most cases the default implementation is good enough, so you simply need to declare `Exception` instances for the types you want to use, e.g.

```
instance Exception Foo
```

Comment: Thanks, simple `throwTo` works. I have never used exceptions before so I'm somewhat lost here. E.g. What to do with the old `Exception` datatype?

Comment: @n.m. Basically, each constructor of the old `Exception` type now corresponds to a separate type and all exceptions are caught dynamically. I wrote [an answer about the new exception interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009384/exception-handling-in-haskell) that may be helpful to you.