# How to catch a divide by zero error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

For something like file not found the basic structure of the code below will work, but for this example of division by zero the exception is not caught. How does one catch a divide by zero?

```
import Control.Exception.Base
import Data.Array

main = toTry `catch` handler

toTry = do
    print "hi"
    print (show (3 `div` 0))
    print "hi"

handler :: IOError -> IO ()
handler e = putStrLn "bad"
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009384/exception-handling-in-haskell

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a handler that catches an [ArithException](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#t:ArithException), and matches on `DivideByZero`.

```
import Control.Exception.Base
import Data.Array

main = toTry `catch` handler

toTry = do
    print "hi"
    print (show (3 `div` 0))
    print "hi"

handler :: ArithException -> IO ()
handler DivideByZero = putStrLn "Divide by Zero!"
handler _ = putStrLn "Some other error..."
```

Comment: Is there something that counts as catch all?

Comment: You can write a handler that catches `SomeException` to catch any exception regardless of type.