# How to catch exception

Tags: haskell, error-handling

How do you handle error in Haskell? Let's say I have function that does division. It returns true if division can be performed otherwise return false.

```
di :: Int -> Bool
di a b = a `div` b
```

How do I catch the exception in this type of scenario so that I can return boolean value? How do I catch all exception not just particular type of exception? I know I can check if b is zero or not but I just want to know error handling.

Update : 
Here's what I have done so far. However I'm getting type mismatch error. Can anyone point out how I can fix this?

```
di :: Int -> Int -> Bool
di a b = do
    result <- try (a `div` b) :: IO (Either SomeException Bool)
    case result of
       Left ex  -> False
       Right val -> True
```

Error

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO b0’ with ‘Bool’
Expected type: IO (Either SomeException Bool)
               -> (Either SomeException Bool -> IO b0) -> Bool
  Actual type: IO (Either SomeException Bool)
               -> (Either SomeException Bool -> IO b0) -> IO b0
```

Comment: there are like 8 ways to that: http://www.randomhacks.net/2007/03/10/haskell-8-ways-to-report-errors/   and http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/08/8-ways-to-report-errors-in-haskell-revisited/

Comment: Note that the `Bool` in `Either SomeException Bool` should be the type of the return value (i.e. `Int` in this case). Also what the error message is telling you is that you are trying to return a `Bool` when the type inferencer wants an `IO something`. In fact the type of your function will be `Int -> Int -> IO Bool` because you cannot escape the `IO` monad. Also, instead of using pattern matching you could use the function `Data.Either.isRight`

Answer (score 2):

Couple of problems with your code:

- `di` runs in the IO monad, so the result type needs to be `IO Bool`
- `try` needs an IO computation, but `div a b` is a pure value, so you need to lift it with `return`.
- Again, `di` returns an `IO Bool`, so the last case statement needs a `return` to lift the case expression to an IO computation.

Here's a version of `di` which type checks:

```
di' :: Int -> Int -> IO Bool
di' a b = do
  r <- try (return (div a b)) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
  return $ case r of
             Left _ -> False
             Right _ -> True
```

However, this version will return `True` for all inputs. The reason is that  due to lazy evaluation the `div` function is never actually called.

One way to fix this is to use the `BangPatterns` pragma to force the evaluation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

di' :: Int -> Int -> IO Bool
di' a b = do
  r <- try (let !x = div a b in return x) :: IO (Either SomeException Int)
  return $ case r of
            Left _ -> False
            Right _ -> True

ghci> di' 3 0
False

ghci> di' 3 1
True
```

Also see this SO question: [How to catch a divide by zero error in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20822365/866915) for details on how to catch only arithmetic exceptions.