# When to use 'ioError . userError' instead of 'error'

Tags: haskell, error-handling

While reading the source code of the [`network` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network), I noticed the extensive use of `ioError (userError ("Error description"))` to raise errors during IO operations.

Since this is not the first time I've seen this, I was wondering what's the difference in *practice* of using this pattern instead of the [`error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v%3aerror) function from `Prelude`.

I'm aware that `ioError . userError` raises an [`IOException`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/System-IO-Error.html#t%3aIOError) in the `IO` monad, while `error` raises a [`ErrorCall`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#t%3aErrorCall) anywhere, but in the end both seem destined to abort the program showing a simple error message.

In which scenarios `ioError . userError` would be advantageous over `error`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's conventional to use `error` only to denote a bug. A bug in the sense that something that the developer expects to never happen has happened. Although `error` does indeed just throw an `ErrorCall` exception, which as such can be caught the same way as any other exception, it's conventional to never catch it, so that the program crashes informing the end-user about the bug with the message provided as a parameter to `error`. Later on the user can post that info on the issue tracker for example.

`IOException`s on the other hand are meant to be caught and are just an adaptation of the standard C/Java control flow. The `userError` is usually used to specify some general case, when none of [the more specific types](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-IO-Exception.html#IOErrorType) like `AlreadyExists` or `ResourceBusy` are appropriate.

---

It must be mentioned that solutions for both of the problems have evolved.

For bug-reporting there exist TemplateHaskell-based libraries such as [**loch-th**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/loch-th) and [**placeholders**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/placeholders), which extend the `error` to refer to a specific location in the source code and other niceties, like "todo" dummies, which let the compilation pass, but with a warning.

The exceptions of any kind are generally acknowledged as a hack into the otherwise neat Haskell's type system. The biggest problem is that both you and the compiler have no information on whether some computation, e.g. `IO ()`, will raise any kind of exception. And that has proven to be awful, with the emergence of a pattern of an exception thrown by some low-level library deeply nested in the dependencies hierarchy crawling out, which then triggers a chain of bug reports on different projects and inflicts tons of pain. That is why complete replacements for the exception-based control-flow have lately been developing, such as [`EitherT` monad transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either) with a related [**errors** util-library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/errors), or the [`ErrorT` transformer](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#t%3aErrorT). Both of the solutions make exceptions explicitly represented in the type system. The `ErrorT` however [has received some criticism](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/07/errors-10-simplified-error-handling.html) in favour of `EitherT`+"errors".

Comment: You could also note what haskell.org says: `An IOException records a more specific error type, a descriptive string and maybe the handle that was used when the error was flagged.`
Also, here's the SO link describing [Haskell's exception handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009384/exception-handling-in-haskell)

Comment: Then, could you say that, by convention, an `ErrorCall` is suppossed to never be caught, but it's alright to catch a `userError` and do some handling with it?

Comment: @DannyNavarro Yes. Exactly.