# Haskell: Debugging a Multithreaded Server

Tags: multithreading, haskell, networking

I'm trying to implement a simple network application in haskell. The application is supposed to start two servers that send packets to one another. See the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env runghc

module Main where

import Network
import System.IO
import Control.Concurrent.Thread as Thread
import Control.Arrow

instance Read PortNumber where
  readsPrec p s = map (first fromInteger) $ readsPrec p s

pingpong :: PortNumber -> IO (IO ())
pingpong port = do
    s <- listenOn $ PortNumber port  -- start server
    print ("listening", "on", port)
    return $ run s                 
  where
    run s = do 
      (h,host,_) <- accept s            -- wait for packet to arrive
      port' <- fmap read $ hGetLine h   -- read dst port from packet
      hClose h
      print ("recved", "from", host, port')
      h <- connectTo host (PortNumber port')  -- send packet back
      print ("connected", "to", port')
      hPutStr h $ show port
      hClose h
      print ("sent", "to", port')

hosts = map pingpong [8080, 8081]

main :: IO ()
main = withSocketsDo $ do
    servers <- sequence hosts   -- start servers
    print "started servers"
    threads <- mapM Thread.forkIO servers  -- start listeners
    h <- connectTo "localhost" (PortNumber 8080)  -- send initial packet
    hPutStr h $ show 8081
    hClose h
    print "sent initial ping to 8081"
```

Running the above code, the two servers start as expected, a packet is sent, but then the receiver just dies without any sort of error-message.

```
("listening","on",8080)
("listening","on",8081)
"started servers"
"sent initial ping to 8081"
("recved","from","localhost",8081)
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong, or how I can debug the problem? I tried using [`catch`/`handle`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009384/exception-handling-in-haskell) and [stack-traces](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging#Stack_trace), but didn't get any valuable additional information.

Comment: Haskell programs exit when the main thread ends regardless of any active sub-threads.

Comment: Look at the port numbers your program is printing. Send a ping to 8081, receive a ping *from 8081*, send a reply to... where?

Comment: BTW, you should use e.g. `putStrLn "sent ping"` and `putStrLn ("received from " ++ show host ++ ":" ++ show port)`. Using `print` will cause strings to be quoted. Not that it matters much in debugging messages, though.