# How to start a console program from another console program?

Tags: haskell, command-line, console

I would like to know how to start a console program `B` (using generated command line instruction) from running Haskell console program `A`, so that user would be able to interact with program `B`, and when the program `B` ended, program `A` would resume.

I want to arrange it as seamlessly as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just launched via a shell command then use [`callCommand`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:callCommand) from `System.Process`.

```
import System.Process
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Inside Haskell, Run emacs?"
  q <- getLine
  when (q == "y") (callCommand "emacs -nw")
  putStrLn "Back inside Haskell"
```

Comment: Generally it's what I want, but if I press `Ctrl-C`, invoked process  fails, so I don't see message `Back inside Haskell`. It's because the created process exit code is not `0`. I think I should use `try` and ignore the exception... Is it a good approach?

Comment: There's a section on this in the documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.2.0.0/docs/System-Process.html#g:4 . Can use the more general createProcess /  getProcessExitCode which can handle signals thrown in the child process more gracefully.

Comment: OK, no problem, now I know where to dig :-) Thanks!

Comment: @fosskers, nice typo ;-)

Comment: @fosskers, how about this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009384/exception-handling-in-haskell/6009807#6009807)? Of course `try` is not for pure code, but how would you handle `IO` action that may fail and throw exception?

Comment: @Mark: How did that `t` slip in there? Haha. As for try/catch, naturally these things are part of the language, but it seems to me something better could be done with an `EitherIO` stack. Exceptions in general break (any semblance of) determinism that a function in the IO Monad has.