# How to handle runtime errors in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, exception, runtime-error

I'm trying to learn Haskell by writing a simple console chess game. It displays a chess board and gets moves from standard input in [SAN notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_notation_(chess)). Here's what I've got so far:

```
import System.IO
import Chess
import Chess.FEN

main = do
  putStrLn "Welcome to Console Chess!"
  putStrLn $ show defaultBoard
  gameLoop defaultBoard

gameLoop board = do
  putStr "Your move: "
  hFlush stdout
  move <- getLine
  let newBoard = moveSAN move board
  case newBoard of
   Left _ -> do
     putStrLn "Invalid move, try again..."
     gameLoop board
   Right b -> do
     putStrLn $ show b
     gameLoop b
```

The problem is that the call to the `moveSAN` function sometimes crashes the program, losing all progress made in the game. For instance, pressing Enter at the "Your move:" prompt produces:

```
Your move: 
cchess: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Otherwise, entering a two-digit number produces:

```
Your move: 11
cchess: Error in array index
```

Entering two periods gives:

```
Your move: ..
cchess: Char.digitToInt: not a digit '.'
```

I would like to catch these errors and inform the user that the move they have entered is not in valid SAN notation. How can I do that?

Comment: Your code is correct. This is a bug in the chesshs library you're using. On bad input it should return `Left NoParse`, but instead it crashes due to the use of partial functions like `head` and `digitToInt` :(

Comment: I agree, the solution is total function, which can only themselves be composed of total functions. You will need to wrap the library calls in a catch statement to make the functions total...

Comment: "You will need to wrap the library calls in a catch statement"

How do I do that?

Comment: This may be informative: [**Exception handling in Haskell**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6009807/1465011)

Comment: The provided answer, `spoon`, is something of a band-aid when you should fix the foundation (though a useful band-aid and the answer is great, not attacking that).  Consider instead: 1) send a patch to the upstream library 2) validate the input before calling the partial function in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an ideal world, you would avoid functions like `head` and not have runtime errors at all. Runtime errors are **fundamentally awkward**, especially in Haskell.

In this case, you want to catch the runtime error. If you're content to turn it into a `Maybe`, you can use the [`spoon`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon) package.

Exceptions in Haskell are subtle thanks to laziness. Particularly, if you don't evaluate the part of the structure that has the exception, it won't fire. This is handled in `spoon` with two different functions:

- `spoon`, which evaluates a structure *deeply* but requires an instance of a special typeclass
- `teaspoon` which only evaluates your structure part of the way to [weak head normal form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872898/haskell-what-is-weak-head-normal-form)

For your case, I think `teaspoon` should be fine. Try checking the result of the parse with:

```
teaspoon (moveSAN move board)
```

which should give you a `Maybe` value.

If that doesn't work, it means you need to evaluate more of the structure to hit the exception. It looks like `Board` does not implement the typeclass needed to deeply evaluate it with `spoon`, so your best bet is a bit hacky: use `spoon` on the result of `show`:

```
spoon (show $ moveSAN move board)
```

This will give you a `Maybe String`. If it's `Just`, the move parsed correctly; if it's `Nothing`, there was an error.

It's worth noting that the `spoon` package doesn't really do much: each function it has is only [a couple of lines](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1/docs/src/Control-Spoon.html#teaspoon). At some point, it's worth figuring out how to handle exceptions in Haskell yourself, but for now `spoon` is just a bit more convenient and should work properly for you.