# Using try for converting String to Float

Tags: haskell

I try to parse a file. It is a list of 3d Points. I coded this function that extracts the first and second number of one line. Now i want to check if the conversion from String to Float(read function) was successfull. I want to return the Point(Just Point2D) if the conversion is successfull and Nothing when the try fails. The Problem is that the case wants an IO but gets a simple Either.
The code is abstracted from this Post: [Exception handling in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009384/exception-handling-in-haskell)

```
-- | reads out of a splitted line the first and second of the list and returns a list of Points2D
    pointExtraction 
        :: [String] 
        -> Maybe Point2D
    pointExtraction (x:y:tail) = do 
        let result = try ( evaluate (createPoint x y )) :: IO (Either SomeException Point2D)
        case result of 
            Left ex -> Nothing        
            Right point -> (Just point)

createPoint :: String -> String -> Point2D
createPoint x y = Point2D (read x) (read y)
```

Exception:

```
Parsing.hs:56:9: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type: IO (Either SomeException Point2D)
                  with actual type: Either a0 b0
    * In the pattern: Left ex
      In a case alternative: Left ex -> Nothing
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case result of
          Left ex -> Nothing
          Right point -> (Just point)
    |
 56 |         Left ex -> Nothing
    |         ^^^^^^^

Parsing.hs:57:9: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type: IO (Either SomeException Point2D)
                  with actual type: Either a1 Point2D
    * In the pattern: Right point
      In a case alternative: Right point -> (Just point)
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        case result of
          Left ex -> Nothing
          Right point -> (Just point)
    |
 57 |         Right point -> (Just point)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many exception related functions like `try` and `evaluate` are restricted to `IO` in Haskell. You could refactor you code to work in `IO`:

```hs
-- | reads out of a splitted line the first and second of the list and returns a list of Points2D
pointExtraction 
    :: [String] 
    -> IO (Maybe Point2D)
pointExtraction (x:y:tail) = do 
    result <- try ( evaluate (createPoint x y )) :: IO (Either SomeException Point2D)
    case result of 
        Left ex -> pure Nothing        
        Right point -> pure (Just point)

createPoint :: String -> String -> Point2D
createPoint x y = Point2D (read x) (read y)
```

But this is not ideal because now you can also only use the `pointExtraction` function in `IO`. This is how `IO` fundamentally works: it always forces the places where it is used to also use `IO`.

The way to prevent this is to avoid using exceptions. Instead you can use the `Maybe` or `Either` type as a return type. There is a version of `read` called [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) in the `Text.Read` module. You can use that to avoid `IO`:

```hs
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

-- | reads out of a splitted line the first and second of the list and returns a list of Points2D
pointExtraction 
    :: [String] 
    -> Maybe Point2D
pointExtraction (x:y:tail) = createPoint x y

createPoint :: String -> String -> Maybe Point2D
createPoint strX strY = do
  x <- readMaybe strX
  y <- readMaybe strY
  pure (Point2D x y)
```